# OpenShift 3 - Build "cannot be started due to lack of disk space"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, diskspace, openshift-origin, device-mapper

When attempting to perform a Build within OpenShift, it immediately fails with the error ***"cannot be started due to lack of disk space"*** showing up in the Events viewer.

I can't seem to figure out why OpenShift is thinking I'm low on disk when everything appears to be fine.  Here are some details on the server.

## # docker -v

```
Docker version 1.8.2-el7, build a01dc02/1.8.2
```

## # docker info

```
    Containers: 2
    Images: 36
    Storage Driver: devicemapper
    Pool Name: docker--vg-docker--pool
    Pool Blocksize: 524.3 kB
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Data file: 
    Metadata file: 
    Data Space Used: 1.923 GB
    Data Space Total: 13.72 GB
    Data Space Available: 11.8 GB
    Metadata Space Used: 688.1 kB
    Metadata Space Total: 37.75 MB
    Metadata Space Available: 37.06 MB
    Udev Sync Supported: true
    Deferred Removal Enabled: true
    Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-12-01)
    Execution Driver: native-0.2
    Logging Driver: json-file
    Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
    Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.1 (Maipo)
    CPUs: 4
    Total Memory: 7.64 GiB
    Name: oshift101.dev.omitted.ca
    ID: BGBJ:475D:NUO6:FORT:ZQQF:TZ4Z:QAX4:7AFK:VCCQ:7WYU:HNI2:5EAC
    WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
```

## # df -h

```
    Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/vg00-root   1014M  770M  245M  76% /
    devtmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                    3.9G  121M  3.8G   4% /run
    tmpfs                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/mapper/vg00-usr     4.0G  1.4G  2.7G  33% /usr
    /dev/mapper/vg00-opt     509M   26M  483M   6% /opt
    /dev/mapper/vg00-tmp     4.0G   33M  4.0G   1% /tmp
    /dev/sda1                509M  109M  400M  22% /boot
    /dev/mapper/vg00-var      12G  3.0G  9.1G  25% /var
    hnas01:/home             250G   83G  168G  33% /home
    hnas01:/docker-registry  512G  6.1G  506G   2% /dockerregistry
    hnas01:/opt-omitted/linux     20G   69M   20G   1% /opt/omitted/nfs
    tmpfs                    3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-dockercfg-budmf-push
    tmpfs                    3.9G  8.0K  3.9G   1% /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/name-ommitted-source
    tmpfs                    3.9G  8.0K  3.9G   1% /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-token-b79p6
```

## # dmsetup status

```
    vg00-tmp: 0 8388608 linear 
    vg00-swap0: 0 8388608 linear 
    vg00-swap0: 8388608 8388608 linear 
    docker--vg-docker--pool: 0 26804224 thin-pool 117 168/9216 3668/26176 - rw no_discard_passdown queue_if_no_space 
    vg00-usr: 0 8388608 linear 
    vg00-var: 0 8388608 linear 
    vg00-var: 8388608 16777216 linear 
    vg00-root: 0 2097152 linear 
    docker--vg-docker--pool_tdata: 0 26804224 linear 
    docker--vg-docker--pool_tmeta: 0 73728 linear 
    vg00-opt: 0 1048576 linear
```

## # dmsetup table

```
    vg00-tmp: 0 8388608 linear 8:2 16779264
    vg00-swap0: 0 8388608 linear 8:2 25167872
    vg00-swap0: 8388608 8388608 linear 8:2 36702208
    docker--vg-docker--pool: 0 26804224 thin-pool 253:6 253:7 1024 0 1 skip_block_zeroing 
    vg00-usr: 0 8388608 linear 8:2 8390656
    vg00-var: 0 8388608 linear 8:2 2048
    vg00-var: 8388608 16777216 linear 8:2 45090816
    vg00-root: 0 2097152 linear 8:2 33556480
    docker--vg-docker--pool_tdata: 0 26804224 linear 8:3 75776
    docker--vg-docker--pool_tmeta: 0 73728 linear 8:3 2048
    vg00-opt: 0 1048576 linear 8:2 35653632
```

## # pvscan

```
    PV /dev/sda2   VG vg00        lvm2 [31.50 GiB / 2.00 GiB free]
    PV /dev/sda3   VG docker-vg   lvm2 [32.00 GiB / 19.14 GiB free]
    Total: 2 [63.49 GiB] / in use: 2 [63.49 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

## # lvscan

```
      ACTIVE            '/dev/docker-vg/docker-pool' [12.78 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/var' [12.00 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/usr' [4.00 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/tmp' [4.00 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/swap0' [8.00 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/root' [1.00 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/opt' [512.00 MiB] inherit
```

## # cat /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage

```
    DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS=--storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.fs=xfs --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/docker--vg-docker--pool --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_removal=true
```

## # mount

```
    proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=3998872k,nr_inodes=999718,mode=755)
    securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
    devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
    tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
    tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
    pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
    cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
    configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
    /dev/mapper/vg00-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
    /dev/mapper/vg00-usr on /usr type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
    systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=36,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
    debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
    mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
    hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
    /dev/mapper/vg00-opt on /opt type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
    /dev/mapper/vg00-tmp on /tmp type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
    /dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
    /dev/mapper/vg00-var on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
    hnas01:/home on /home type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.139.0.11,mountvers=3,mountport=4048,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=10.139.0.11)
    hnas01:/docker-registry on /dockerregistry type nfs (ro,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.139.0.11,mountvers=3,mountport=4048,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=10.139.0.11)
    hnas01:/opt-omitted/linux on /opt/omitted/nfs type nfs (ro,relatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.139.0.11,mountvers=3,mountport=4048,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=10.139.0.11)
    binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
    tmpfs on /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-dockercfg-budmf-push type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
    tmpfs on /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/johnadacssh6-source type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
    tmpfs on /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-token-b79p6 type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
```

Edited to add the following additional details.

Still having a problem with this.  It's looking like it may actually be in Kubernetes that the problem exists, but I'm not sure.

I ran the following GO program, based on what Kubernetes uses for determining whether or not there's enough disk space.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    pathArg := os.Args[1]

    stat := syscall.Statfs_t{}
    err := syscall.Statfs(pathArg, &stat)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    //bsize := stat.Bsize
    //fmt.Println(stat)
    s := fmt.Sprintf(`
    Statfs_t {
        Type    %d
        Bsize   %d
        Blocks  %d
        Bfree   %d
        Bavail  %d
        Files   %d
        Ffree   %d
        Frsize  %d
        Flags   %d
    }
    `, stat.Type,
        stat.Bsize,
        stat.Blocks,
        stat.Bfree,
        stat.Bavail,
        stat.Files,
        stat.Ffree,
        stat.Frsize,
        stat.Flags)

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

I then ran it via the following

```
for x in $(sudo df -h | grep -v Filesys| awk '{print $6}'); do echo "Running on $x"; sudo ./fsinfo $x; done;
```

And received the following results, which don't seem to show any disk space issues either.

I'm wondering if I should submit this as a bug report to Kubernetes?

Running on /

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    1481003842
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  259584
    Bfree   62600
    Bavail  62600
    Files   1048576
    Ffree   878047
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /dev

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    16914836
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  999718
    Bfree   999718
    Bavail  999718
    Files   999718
    Ffree   999333
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   34
}
```

Running on /dev/shm

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    16914836
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1001444
    Bfree   1001444
    Bavail  1001444
    Files   1001444
    Ffree   1001443
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   38
}
```

Running on /run

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    16914836
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1001444
    Bfree   923475
    Bavail  923475
    Files   1001444
    Ffree   1000914
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   38
}
```

Running on /sys/fs/cgroup

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    16914836
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1001444
    Bfree   1001444
    Bavail  1001444
    Files   1001444
    Ffree   1001431
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   46
}
```

Running on /usr

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    1481003842
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1046016
    Bfree   703392
    Bavail  703392
    Files   4194304
    Ffree   4155732
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /opt

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    1481003842
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  130219
    Bfree   123593
    Bavail  123593
    Files   524288
    Ffree   524263
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /tmp

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    1481003842
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1046016
    Bfree   1037760
    Bavail  1037760
    Files   4194304
    Ffree   4194273
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /boot

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    1481003842
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  130219
    Bfree   102353
    Bavail  102353
    Files   524288
    Ffree   523955
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /var

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    1481003842
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  3143168
    Bfree   2416721
    Bavail  2416721
    Files   12582912
    Ffree   12579830
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /home

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    26985
    Bsize   32768
    Blocks  8192000
    Bfree   5523429
    Bavail  5523429
    Files   2682388480
    Ffree   1534765937
    Frsize  32768
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /dockerregistry

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    26985
    Bsize   32768
    Blocks  16777216
    Bfree   16578608
    Bavail  16578608
    Files   1072955392
    Ffree   659992996
    Frsize  32768
    Flags   4129
}
```

Running on /opt/cbc/nfs

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    26985
    Bsize   32768
    Blocks  655360
    Bfree   653153
    Bavail  653153
    Files   1072955392
    Ffree   659992996
    Frsize  32768
    Flags   4129
}
```

Running on /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-dockercfg-bsamf-push

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    16914836
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1001444
    Bfree   1001443
    Bavail  1001443
    Files   1001444
    Ffree   1001442
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/omitted6-source

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    16914836
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1001444
    Bfree   1001442
    Bavail  1001442
    Files   1001444
    Ffree   1001441
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

Running on /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/19fb86f1-d9b1-11e5-bb64-005056969894/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/builder-token-b7asp6

```
Statfs_t {
    Type    16914836
    Bsize   4096
    Blocks  1001444
    Bfree   1001442
    Bavail  1001442
    Files   1001444
    Ffree   1001441
    Frsize  4096
    Flags   4128
}
```

## # lvs

```
# lvs -o +lv_major,lv_minor,lv_kernel_major,lv_kernel_minor,lv_size,seg_count,snap_percent,segtype,stripes,stripesize,chunksize,seg_start,seg_size

LV          VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Maj Min KMaj KMin LSize   #Seg Snap%  Type      #Str Stripe Chunk   Start SSize  
docker-pool docker-vg twi-a-t---  12.78g             13.62  1.71                              -1  -1  253    8  12.78g    1        thin-pool    1     0  512.00k    0   12.78g
opt         vg00      -wi-ao---- 512.00m                                                      -1  -1  253    5 512.00m    1        linear       1     0       0     0  512.00m
root        vg00      -wi-ao----   1.00g                                                      -1  -1  253    1   1.00g    1        linear       1     0       0     0    1.00g
swap0       vg00      -wi-ao----   8.00g                                                      -1  -1  253    2   8.00g    2        linear       1     0       0     0    4.00g
swap0       vg00      -wi-ao----   8.00g                                                      -1  -1  253    2   8.00g    2        linear       1     0       0  4.00g   4.00g
tmp         vg00      -wi-ao----   4.00g                                                      -1  -1  253    4   4.00g    1        linear       1     0       0     0    4.00g
usr         vg00      -wi-ao----   4.00g                                                      -1  -1  253    0   4.00g    1        linear       1     0       0     0    4.00g
var         vg00      -wi-ao----  12.00g                                                      -1  -1  253    3  12.00g    2        linear       1     0       0     0    4.00g
var         vg00      -wi-ao----  12.00g                                                      -1  -1  253    3  12.00g    2        linear       1     0       0  4.00g   8.00g
```

Comment: @mick, Thanks for the reply.  Please see updated question above with lvs at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a week of this problem the issue has resolved itself.  It's great that it's working, but very annoying that I still don't know what caused the problem to begin with, nor what fixed it in the end.  It simply stopped reporting the out of disk error and builds performed as normal.